# AS3 random symbol movement loop with easing?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I have cobbled together a script for making a movie symbol randomly move around the stage. My aim is to make it slowly hover around in one spot.

Problem is that it's pretty buggy and the position of the symbol always starts in the top left of the stage. I would really like to find a way to add easing into the script too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Declare Globals
var currentFrameCount: int = 300;
var totalFrameCount: int = 300;
this.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
this.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
var destinationX: Number = this.x;
var destinationY: Number = this.y;
var initialX: Number;
var initialY: Number;
var distanceX: Number;
var distanceY: Number;
var xProg: Number;
var yProg: Number;

var countFrame: int = 0;
var delay: int = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callDelay);
function callDelay(e: Event) {
    countFrame++;
    delayEvent(delay);
}
//Code to move the object to a random location and give it a random target to move to.
function spawnObject() {
    destinationX = Math.round(Math.random() * 200); //random destination
    destinationY = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
    currentFrameCount = 30;
    initialX = this.x;
    initialY = this.y;
    distanceX = destinationX - initialX; //distance between destination and initial
    distanceY = destinationY - initialY;
    yProg = distanceY / totalFrameCount;
}

function delayEvent(period) {
    if ((countFrame) >= period) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callDelay);
        timedEvent();
        countFrame = 0;
        return;
    }
}

function timedEvent(): void {
    currentFrameCount = totalFrameCount;
    this.x = destinationX;
    this.y = destinationY;
    spawnObject(); //move the object to a new location and give new destination
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveTo); //add an event listener to move the object around
}

function moveTo(e: Event): void {
    currentFrameCount++;
    if (currentFrameCount < totalFrameCount) {
        this.x += xProg; //incrase x by the x step value
        this.y += yProg; //increase y by the y step value
    } else {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveTo); // remvoe this event listener
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is all actionscript and not javadcript you should remove the jquery tag.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! Have removed it.

Comment: Simplest easing function you can use is this x = (destinationX - x) * dampening_factor
where dampening_factor is between 0 and 1 - experiment and see what works best for you